# Print Current Statement in GDB

Tags: c, gdb

Each time I step with `n` it prints out the next statement to be executed.

How do I see the next statement to be executed, as if I had typed `n`, but without actually stepping the code?

Currently I am using `where`, and this gives me the line number of the next statement and I can use `list` to see some source code. Does it require two separate commands to get what I want?

Comment: Also consider running `gdb --tui`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define yourself a `macro` in your `.gdbinit` in your home-directory.

```
define shownext
where
list
end
```

Well, I am not sure if what I stated works out, but see [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-gdb.html) on how to do things like this.

Comment: For some reason running `list` twice in a row moves the code focus/window.

Comment: @infact - this is the defined behaviour.  The documentation states "If the last lines printed were printed with a list command, this prints lines following the last lines printed;"

Answer (score 2):

Try "frame" command. You will see something like this:

```
   (gdb) frame
   #0 main () at dummy.c:11
   11    FILE*f = fopen("somefile","r");
   (gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your gdb was built with Python support, this [list.current.py](https://github.com/scottt/gdb-python-scripts/blob/master/list-current.py) script would add a new **list-current** gdb command that does what you want.

Sample session:

```
$ gdb -x list-current.py /bin/true
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4014c0: file true.c, line 59.
Starting program: /usr/bin/true 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde88) at true.c:59
59    if (argc == 2)
(gdb) list-current 
59    if (argc == 2)
(gdb) list-current  3
59    if (argc == 2)
60      {
61        initialize_main (&argc, &argv);
(gdb) list-current  -2
58       argument.  */
59    if (argc == 2)
(gdb)
```